# Is it possible to use variable names in eclipse project references?

Tags: eclipse

I'd like to parameterize the references to some projects depending on the workspace, for automatic build of dependent projects. I'm using the workspace `Build Variables` to define the variables that define the project names to be referenced by, i.e for include folders, with no problems, but I can't define them in `Project References` and, if I edit the `.project` file, those variables are ignored.

How can I do that parametization?

Comment: Variables are not supported in .project files.

Comment: @greg-449 Any workaround?

Comment: As a workaround, you can write an Eclipse plugin that does this (e.g. change the project references based on some project settings on start-up).